# Testing MySQL queries with PHPUnit

Tags: mysql, testing, pdo, phpunit, integration-testing

I have some classes purely responsible for constructing SQL strings given some arguments. Now I want to create integration tests to verify the created SQL is actually runs as expected against MySQL.

I have the following test code, which is working fine.

```
class PDOQueryInterfaceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
        exec( "mysql -e 'create database test_wikibase_database;'" );
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass() {
        exec( "mysql -e 'drop database test_wikibase_database;'" );
    }

    public function testConnection() {
        $pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_wikibase_database;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password' );

        // code doing stuff with $pdo
    }

}
```

The problem with it is that the username and password are hardcoded. Is there a way to have PHPUnit accept parameters for these, or use some config file that specifies them?

Also, is there generally a better way of doing this kind of integration tests? The way the database is constructed and whatnot all seems a bit brittle. If I was testing for SQLite, I could have an in-memory database - is this also somehow possible with MySQL?

Comment: You could set the values in the test as strings and use them, or globals from the bootstrap.

Comment: Have you tested the query building itself with PHPUnit?  If not, that would be the best, then use mock objects to test the functionality.  When you want to finally test the integration, you could look to use the DBUnit extension of PHPUnit.